# What is the difference between ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, registerstartupscript

I try to register a script below the  however I get it within the

I use the following however did not manage to get it on the place I want it.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Page)
        {
            Page p = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;

            if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(p) != null)
            {                                                                                                                                                                    
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(p, typeof(string), "_pane", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var dm = document.getElementById('_pane');dm.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false); </script>", false);
            }
            else
            {
                p.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "_pane", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var dm = document.getElementById('_pane');dm.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false); </script>", true);
            }
        }
```

Pretty sure I miss some details, however after a good research cannot find anything about this, any help would be appriciated

Comment: "however did not manage to get it on the place I want it." - could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Kev, I want it below the </html> tag and now its gets just before the </form> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegisterClientScriptBlock` injects script at the top of the page.

`RegisterStartupScript` injects script into your page such that it will be executed when the page finished loading but before the `OnLoad` event is fired:

Sources:

> [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)
>
> [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)